# how to use bing translator api in my website coded in PHP and mobile jquery?

Tags: bing-api, microsoft-translator

i want to use bing translator api in my PHP based website in mobile jquery framework, i have generated Client ID and Client Secret Code  but  it shows an error Error in bing App id ???

Comment: Can you post what you have done until now?

Comment: Hey i have copy this code from a website...

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    
     $.ajax(
                {
                  //url: "Default.aspx/GetBingAppId",
                  //type: 'post',
                  //dataType: "json",
                  data: "{}",
                  //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  success: function (bingid) {
                    return $("p,h1,h2,span,li,a,.xlatext,.clients").translator({ appID: bingid.d, languageListNode: $('#languages').get(0), callback: xlatDone });
                  },

Comment: error: function (x, err, desc) {
                    alert('Error getting Bing ID: ' + err + ' - ' + desc);
                  }
                }
              );
     
    });
    function xlatDone(charsXlated) {
      if (charsXlated === 0) return;
      $.ajax(
        {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'Default.aspx/SaveCharactersTranslated',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: "{charsXlated:" + charsXlated + "}"
        }
      );
    }